# How to control the RPATH of a launcher created with "dotnet publish --self-contained" on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, elf, rpath

When using `dotnet publish --self-contained` one gets a launcher that has a hard-coded RPATH as follows:

```
$ llvm-readelf-16 -d launcher
Dynamic section at offset 0x217b0 contains 33 entries:
  Tag                Type           Name/Value
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libm.so.6]
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libc.so.6]
  0x000000000000000f (RPATH)        Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/netcoredeps]
...
```

I already attempted to solve this with `LDFLAGS` while invoking `dotnet publish`. Alas, I think `ld` isn't even getting invoked under the hood and therefore this has no effect.

So my question: is there a way to control the RPATH of a launcher created with `dotnet publish`?

PS: using .NET 6.x currently on Ubuntu 22.04 (the packaged .NET).

Answer (score 2):

Judging by this

> The main executable of published .NET Core applications ... has an
> RPATH property set to $ORIGIN/netcoredeps

it is not meant to be configurable.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/Documentation/self-contained-linux-apps.md

There's always [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf) which you can use to edit or remove the RPATH after the fact.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of `patchelf`, but had hoped there's a way to do it "within" .NET. I'll wait a little more before accepting your answer. Still hoping for some alternative.